# How do i twist two objects together

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry

I'm trying to do a candle stand which has two twisted pieces merging together, how do i take my ]two twisted pieces and then twist those around one another?. [image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Add an empty between both objects

[image: Empty between objects]

2. Add a simple deform modifier to each object

   - Set origin to the empty
   - The axis to Z
   - At deform you can chose the twisting angle

[image: Objects with simple-deform modifier]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Of course *Simple Deform* is the easiest way to do it...

If you don't like the easy way you can do it with a spiral and a *Curve* modifier:

- Create your twisted object with a *Simple Deform* modifier.

[image]

- Array it if you want to make it longer.

[image]

- Create a *Curve* > *Curve Spirals* > *Archemedian*. Make it 360° or several times 360°. Put its origin on its bottom.

[image]

- Put your object at the same position as the spiral with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*.

[image]

- Give your object a *Curve* modifier with the spiral as *Object*.

[image]

- Link-duplicate both your object and your spiral with an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, move it a bit so that it twist around the other. You can edit the object or the spiral the way you want, the modifications will be duplicated on the other object and spiral.

[image]

Comment: This solution has a big advantage: using twist/simple deform will twist the base meshes eventually more than wanted. Here the curve allows to avoid that and to start with meshes that are not "twisted based" themselves.

Comment: mmh yes maybe, actually I tried with the Simple Deform but I gave up, I don't remember why...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a plane and adding it a screw modifier then a twist simple deform modifier:

[image]

The screw modifier need to have enough *'steps'* (here 64) so that the shape can deform.

The simple deform modifier, twist mode, is set with an empty as axis origin. This empty is **rotated 90° around Y**.

We can notice that the twist enforce the screw effect, so that the twist is finally a combination of the angles of both modifiers (to be tune as you want).

Now, if you just duplicate the mesh and place the dupli on the side of the first one, the dupli will turn around it:

[image]

And if finally, you move the empty just between the two meshes, they twist around each other:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked beautifully and was exactly what i was looking for.